# How do I pass custom claims via ASP.NET Identity's FacebookAuthenticationProvider?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2, owin-middleware

Starting with Visual Studio's "Web API" project template, I am attempting to add custom claims to the token created by the `/Api/Account/ExternalLogin` endpoint. I add these via the `FacebookAuthenticationProvider.OnAuthenticated` callback, but they do not persist through to the `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.AuthorizationEndpointResponse()`.

> Note: I am using a similar approach as documented by Rahul Nath in his article [ASP.NET Web API and External Login - Authenticating with Social Networks](http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/asp-dot-net-web-api-and-external-login-authenticating-with-social-networks/)

### Code

In my `Startup.Auth.cs` class's `ConfigureAuth()` method (which is called from the `OwinStartup` class's `Configuration()` method) I added a callback function to the `OnAuthenticated` property in order to set a single claim, `foo`, with the value `bar`:

```cs
var facebookAuthenticationProvider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider() 
{
    OnAuthenticated = (context) => 
    {
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("foo", "bar"));
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
};
```

I then add the `FacebookAuthenticationProvider` instance to a new `FacebookAuthenticationOptions` object:

```cs
var facebookAuthenticationOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions() 
{
    AppId = "XXXX",
    AppSecret = "YYYY",
    Provider = facebookAuthenticationProvider
};
```

And pass that onto OWIN's `UseFacebookAuthentication()` method:

```cs
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthenticationOptions);
```

### Results

If I put a breakpoint in the `OnAuthenticated` callback I can see that my custom claim is being added, as are a number of other claims (including a couple from the `urn:facebook` namespace). So far so good.

When I examine my claims via the `AuthorizationEndpointResponse()` method of my `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` class after a Facebook authentication, however, there are only two claims available in the `context.Identity.Claims` collection:

- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier
- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name

All of the `urn:facebook` claims have been removed, as has my custom `foo` claim. I'm assuming some other location in the pipeline is recreating the identity with a barebones set of claims, but I am not sure where.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have following code for accessing custom Claims:

```
 public class AppUser : ClaimsPrincipal{
    public AppUser(ClaimsPrincipal principal): base(principal){}
    public string Role{
        get{
            return this.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
        }
    }  

    public string ProfileID{
        get{
            return this.FindFirst("ProfileID").Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to edit the ExternalLoginData private class to include the additional claims you want to pass along through the flow. In the default VS2013 template class files, this private class can be found in the AccountController.cs file.

I was having a similar problem, not able to pass email from Google claims, and this solved the problem (note the added "Email" variable and references to it in both methods:

```
private class ExternalLoginData
{
    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public string ProviderKey { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public IList<Claim> GetClaims()
    {
        IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, ProviderKey, null, LoginProvider));

        if (UserName != null)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserName, null, LoginProvider));
        }

        if (Email != null)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, Email, null, LoginProvider));
        }

        return claims;
    }

    public static ExternalLoginData FromIdentity(ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        if (identity == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Claim providerKeyClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        if (providerKeyClaim == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(providerKeyClaim.Issuer)
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(providerKeyClaim.Value))
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (providerKeyClaim.Issuer == ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new ExternalLoginData
        {
            LoginProvider = providerKeyClaim.Issuer,
            ProviderKey = providerKeyClaim.Value,
            UserName = identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name),
            Email = identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)
        };
    }
}
```